# How can I assert that a Tensor is a sequence of 0 to N `True`s, followed by 0 to N `False`s?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

How can I assert that a Tensor looks like the following (for example):

```
[ True, True ]
[ True, True, True, False, False, False, False ]
[ True, True, True, False, False ]
[ True, False, False, False, False ]
[ False, False ]
```

but reject inputs like these:

```
[ True, False, True, False, False, True, False ]
[ False, False, False, False, True ]
```

Or more generally speaking: I want to test whether a Tensor only consists of a sequence of 0 to N values of True, followed by 0 to N values of False. How can I do that with Tensorflow 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, studying the indices of the elements:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def is_valid(t):
  where_false = tf.where(~t)
  return len(where_false) == 0 or all( idx_true < min(where_false) for idx_true in tf.where(t))

assert is_valid(tf.constant([ True, True ]))
assert is_valid(tf.constant([ True, True, True, False, False, False, False ]))
assert is_valid(tf.constant([ True, True, True, False, False ]))
assert is_valid(tf.constant([ True, False, False, False, False ]))
assert is_valid(tf.constant([ False, False ]))
assert not is_valid(tf.constant([ True, False, True, False, False, True, False ]))
assert not is_valid(tf.constant([ False, False, False, False, True ]))
```

The idea is, all True values should appear before the first False, if any exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can do that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def is_valid(a):
    # a is assumed to be a 1D boolean array
    a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
    # Convert to integer
    a_int = tf.dtypes.cast(a, tf.int32)
    # Take pairwise differences
    diff = a_int[1:] - a_int[:-1]
    # Check all differences are zero or negative (no transitions from False to True)
    return tf.reduce_all(diff <= 0)

# Valid examples
tf.print(is_valid([ True, True ]))
# 1
tf.print(is_valid([ True, True, True, False, False, False, False ]))
# 1
tf.print(is_valid([ True, True, True, False, False ]))
# 1
tf.print(is_valid([ True, False, False, False, False ]))
# 1
tf.print(is_valid([ False, False ]))
# 1

# Invalid examples
tf.print(is_valid([ True, False, True, False, False, True, False ]))
# 0
tf.print(is_valid([ False, False, False, False, True ]))
# 0
```

Note: `is_valid` returns a scalar boolean tensor, even though `tf.print` prints it as an integer.